# Unable to download a PDF from my ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, download

In the past I was using the following technique to achieve this, but right now it is not working, and I do not know why.

```
<a to="/assets/documents/Dzenis-H.pdf" download>
    <img src={CV} alt="Draft CV" />
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following mistakes:

- Instead of writing `href` I wrote `to`
- In React you actually have to import the file and use that inside of the `href`

So here's the updated and working code:

```
import Resume from "../documents/Dzenis-H.pdf";


<a href={Resume} download>
   <img src={CV} alt="Draft CV" />
</a>
```